# map versus list comprehension in function return

Tags: python, matplotlib

Simple question:

Matplotlib has a function that returns two values:

```
locs,label = plt.yticks()
```

Pylint complains about this line, telling me "Used builtin function map". So I went to pylint site and found this: http://pylint-messages.wikidot.com/messages:w0141
So, I'm trying to fix this warning using list comprehension. But what is the correct form?

```
[(locs,label) for plt.yticks()]
```

is not working.

Thanks!

EDIT: I made a simple test script to try to show the problem, and the problem was one line below:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

""" docstring """

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

LOCS, LABEL = plt.yticks()

plt.yticks(LOCS, map(lambda x: "%.2f" % x, LOCS)) # offending line

print(LOCS)
```

So duh, I was looking on the wrong line. How this lambda can be adjusted to list comprehension? Thanks

Comment: Sounds like it's actually complaining about `yticks()` to me, which is kinda odd...

Comment: plt.yticks() return two values, so I thought that it was complaining of attributing both values at the same time, like a map().

Comment: And it doesn't complain if you remove that line? Maybe you misinterpret the output, because, well, I don't see any `map` there (and you can't replace it with a list comprehension either, because you *are not mapping*). Can you produce a minimal Python file that demonstrates the issue and post it here?

Comment: It's possible it was actually talking about the line before or after this one.

Comment: Oh, and by the way, for me it complains about the missing space after comma. You should really supply an example file.

Comment: That was the case. Stupid dixlesya.

Comment: I am not getting any errors from running the example script you have. It returns some kind of a combination of arrays and tuples and objects. What seems to be the problem again?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
locs,label = plt.yticks()
```

Is the correct way to receive two variables from a function. You could receive it as a single variable, and work with the tuple object, but that would be pointless.

It's possible that pylint is complaining about `plt.yticks`. Apart from it being out of your control, it is not *in general* preferable to use a list comprehension instead of `map`, just in a wide variety of cases.

In the case of `plt.yticks(LOCS, map(lambda x: "%.2f" % x, LOCS))`, a list comprehension is likely to be more readable, and *may* be faster.